# variable value not getting printed to console

Tags: node.js, function

I have the below function

```
child.stderr.on('data', function(data, callback) {
  getEventLog.getId(uuid, function(err, id, code, callback){
    getEventLog.getDuration(id, uuid, function(err, duration, callback){
      jobRun.duration = duration;

        var logMessage =
          "Completed jobRunId " + jobRun.id + " (" + jobRun.jobsId + ") " + jobRun.jobType +
            " run " + jobRun.runNumber + " in " + jobRun.duration +  "ms with exit code " + code;
            console.log(logMessage);
        jobRunDbService.update(jobRun, function(data, error){
          if (error) {
            console.log("ERROR on job run update");
            console.log(error);
            //res.json(error);
            return;
          }
      })
    });
  });
});
```

For `console.log(logMessage);` everything gets printed to console correctly except code. It appears as undefined. Is there anything wrong with my function which would be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not appear to be causing this. the "getEventLog.getId" function is apparently passing you an undefined value for code.

Comment: thanks for that. Its getting passed to "getEventLog.getId" but nothing is actually done with it there? Is it possible to change this so it isn't passed but prints a relevant value rathern than undefined?

Comment: It's not getting passed to getEventLog.getId at all, is what I'm suggesting. The code is never getting sent.

Maybe something like child.stderr.on('data', function(data, callback) {
  getEventLog.getId(uuid, function(err, id, data.code, callback){ would work, if the code is part of the data. ...Where is getEventLog.getId getting its "code" from? That's the question.

Answer (score 0):

`code` did not belong there. It should have been in child.stderr.on('close'). Moving it there solved my problem.

I ended up with this:

```
child.on('close', function(code) {
    ....
});
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out.